# How to use multiple Backend Listeners in different Thread Group

Tags: jmeter

I have built an environment (Jmeter_3.1 + InfluxDB_0.13.0 + Grafana_3.1.0 on one VM) and wanna display the real time data when JMeter is executing testing. Successfully, I can see the data in InfluxDB when using one Backend Listener in a simple JMeter testing.

Based on this quick test, I start to use two Backend Listeners because I wanna monitor both Read and Write operations in one JMeter testing.

Here adds the snapshot, **settings of the JMX file**

[image]

- Use Include Controller to call read.jmx
- Use Include Controller to call write.jmx
- Call Backend Listeners in each Thread Group.
- Each Backend Listener uses different **rootMetricsPrefix**

However, after the JMeter testing starts, I only see the Read related data in InfluxDB. I have tried to add the Backend Listener in called `read.jmx / write.jmx`, but got the same result.

Could someone help to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling also on this...Just give another name to the backend listener (the first read; the second write) and it just worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

you have set summaryOnly to false but samplerList is empty , that might be your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried to set `summaryOnly` to true but also get the same result: only read related data displays in InfluxDB...